# Years written in a sequence

Tags: numbers

Writing a sequence of years, 1970, 71, 72, 87, 88, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98

Which is best: 1970 - 72, 87 - 88, 92 - 98
or: 1970 - 72, 87, 88, 92 - 98

It is the 87, 88 that cause confusion. Should they be hyphenated as a string?
Thank you
David Hayhoe
UK

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. "Which is best" questions are not well-suited to the Stack Exchange format, as rarely will there be complete consensus on such matters, and one's personal preference may be overruled by one's editor or house style. I would encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better familiarity with the way to formulate strong SE questions.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would write the sequence of years as

> From 1970-72, 1987-88, and 1992-98.

I found a reference

> **Inclusive years** (Chicago 8.71):
>
> When referring to years within the same century but after the first year of that century, use this style:
>
> the war of 1914-18
>   1968-72
>   the years 1701-4
>   1701-68
>
> When referring to different centuries or a time span when the century changes, repeat all the digits:
>   the years 1597-1601
>   the winter of 1900-1901
>   fiscal year 2000-2001

[3.4 Numbers and Dates](http://lcweb2.loc.gov/ammem/ndlpedit/handbook/numberdate.html)

Answer (score -1):

I see no reason not to link 87 and 88 with a hyphen (or en dash) but, as the previous answer suggested, I would repeat the "19": 1987-88.

Comment: Hello, Green. Note that Mari-Lou's answer contains an authoritative reference. And precedes yours.

Comment: Hi, Edwin. I'm sorry, but I don't understand why you've notified me of this. She added the reference after I responded; and I responded primarily to place an emphasis that not only would I (in agreement) with Mari-Lou  have 1977-78, but that, declaratively, I saw no reason not to link them, as the original poster expressed a doubt about that which I felt hadn't been directly addressed.

Comment: The answer above (now, at least) complies with ELU requirements that authoritative references should be given if at all possible. This answer adds little to that answer other than 'I agree' (which does not constitute an allowable 'answer' here).

Comment: As I said, I did add the one thing (the specific answer to the very specific question about 87 and 88; if you don't consider the added emphasis I provided significant, well, I disagree), and, for the rest, may I suggest you consider not criticizing people for not having had the psychic ability to predict in advance that another person was going amend their response after the person you're criticizing had begun responding? It isn't constructive or helpful.

Comment: Thank you. It seems recommended to link 87 with 88, ie 87-88. I wouldn't keep putting 19 for the century. My book will have over 500 pages of stats and years on Formula 1. Therefore it refers to 1950 onwards.  So in this case 1970 - 72, 87 - 88, 92 - 98  would seem a good option.